# Linq not working with Khmer unicode

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, unicode, linq-to-entities

I have develop with sample Application in C# .Net framework 4.0 and sql server 2008. when query with linq with method contain is not working with khmer unicode.

Note : field is already with type NVARCHAR

Sample of structure table :

```
Person (id, name nvarchar(200))

Linq part :

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Person>();

String strName = "ក";

predicate = predicate.And(e => e.Person.name.Contains(strName));

var query = Person.where(predicate);

return query.ToList();
```

The result all records that the name starting with "ក" is not display in view.

Could you please provide me an solution ?

---

The model class to map with table:

```
[Table(Name = "machine.PERSON")]
public class PersonModel : IEntity {
  [Column(Name = "id", DbType = "numeric(18,0) NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
  public long Id { get; set; }
  [Column(Name = "name", DbType = "nvarchar(255) NULL")]
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

The sample linq code to search value from db:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<PersonModel>(); 
String strName = "ក";
predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Name.StartsWith(); 
var q = PersonModel.Where(predicate); 
var result = from P in q select new {P.Id, P.Name}; return result.ToList();
```

The Sql statement transfer by linq:

```
SELECT [t0].[id] AS [Id], [t0].[name] AS [Name]
FROM [machine].[PERSON] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[name] LIKE @p0
```

Comment: What ORM are you using? Also, can you get the SQL statement that's being executed?

Comment: Can you provide the SQL Statement that was generated and executed too?  See here for example of how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1828123/111013

Comment: Here is the sample code using in my app :

The model class to map with table : 


       [Table(Name = "machine.PERSON")]
       public class PersonModel : IEntity
       {
           [Column(Name = "id",
               DbType = "numeric(18,0) NOT NULL IDENTITY",
               IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
           public long Id { get; set; }
           [Column(Name = "name",
               DbType = "nvarchar(255) NULL")]
           public String Name { get; set; }
       }

Comment: The sample linq code to search value from db :
    
     var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<PersonModel>();
     String strName = "ក"
     predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Name.StartsWith();
               
     var q = PersonModel.Where(predicate);
     var result = from P in q
                  select new {P.Id, P.Name};
        
    return result.ToList();
    
    
    The Sql  statement transfer by linq : 
    
     SELECT [t0].[id] AS [Id], [t0].[name] AS [Name]
             FROM [machine].[PERSON] AS [t0]
             WHERE [t0].[name] LIKE @p0

Comment: You'll also need to find out how @p0 is declared, and it's value - if that's *NOT* declared as an NVARCHAR, then this could be why it's failing.

Comment: @Khlasor, you can edit your post, code is better to read that way. See my edit.

Comment: @Khlasor - the code that you put in the comments, which a couple of us have put up in the actual question, looks incorrect as written.  There was a missing semicolon, and your predicate assignment is missing a closing semicolon.  Can you please edit the question and paste actual code?

Comment: Hello Will Hughes, p0 isn't variable it is sql statement that generated by linq at the runtime. and it's value from text box that I input.